# Site not open using curl?

Tags: curl

```
$your_url = "https://consumablesandstores.com/";
//$your_url = "https://www.sancuro.com/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $your_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); // Required for HTTP error codes to be reported via our call to curl_error($ch)
curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);

if (isset($error_msg)) {
}
```

we have to check our live site to open using curl but it's showing blank.Another site is open 
please give me solution what is exact issue? How to resolve?

Comment: I get `401 Authorization Required`. It seems like you're not providing enough context in your question. How is your question related to [tag:amazon-web-services]?

Comment: how to resolve this issue?@lexicore

Comment: There are many ways to host a site on AWS.

Comment: what is exact issue? @lexicore

Comment: We have no idea how exactly do you your website on AWS. So it is impossible to say anything about what the problem is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

if you modify your code like this:

```
if (isset($error_msg)) {echo $error_msg;}
```

it will show you the error:

> The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized

You might need to provide authorization details, i.e.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"myusername:mypassword");
```